# Redirect to a different page after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How do would you go about redirecting to different page when a user correctly fills a form? I have tried two different methods: `location.href = "otherpage.html";` and `location.replace("otherpage.html")`  however they aren't working.

Adding `window.` in front isn't changing anything either.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="javascript/srcipt.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
    <form name="form" onsubmit="Distance();" method="POST">
        <p>
            <label for="dLondon">Distance from London</label>
            <input type="number" id="dLondon" name="dLondon" min="0" required>
            <label for="dLondon">miles</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="dCanberra">Distance from Canberra</label>
            <input type="number" id="dCanberra" name="dCanberra" min="0" required>
            <label for="dCanberra">miles</label>
        </p>        
        <p>
            <label for="dOttawa">Distance from Ottawa</label>
            <input type="number" id="dOttawa" name="dOttawa" min="0" required>
            <label for="dOttawa">miles</label>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</html>
```

```js
function Distance() {
    let dLondon = document.forms["form"]["dLondon"].value;
    let dOttawa = document.forms["form"]["dOttawa"].value;
    let dCanberra = document.forms["form"]["dCanberra"].value;
    if ((3900 <= dLondon) && ( dLondon <= 5200)) {
        if ((5500 <= dCanberra) && (dCanberra <= 6700)) {
            if ((6700 <= dOttawa) && (dOttawa <= 9300)) {
                location.href = "otherpage.html";
            }
            else {
                alert("Ottawa Distance isn't correct !");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Canberra distance isn't correct !");
        }
    }
    else {
alert("London Distance isn't correct ! ");
}
}
```

Comment: Use the form's [action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) attribute.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, I just had to change `onsbumit="Distance()";` to `obsubmit="return Distance();` in html and add `return false;` at the end of the `Distance()` function.

```js
function Distance() {
    let dLondon = document.forms["form"]["dLondon"].value;
    let dToronto = document.forms["form"]["dToronto"].value;
    let dCanberra = document.forms["form"]["dCanberra"].value;
    let conditionLondon = false;
    let conditionCanberra = false;
    let conditionToronto = false;

    
    if ((3900 <= dLondon) && (dLondon <= 5200)) {
        conditionLondon = true;
    }
    else {
        alert("London Distance isn't correct ! ");
    }

    if ((5500 <= dCanberra) && (dCanberra <= 6700)) {
        conditionCanberra = true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Canberra distance isn't correct !");
    }

    if ((6700 <= dToronto) && (dToronto <= 9300)) {
        conditionToronto = true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Toronto Distance isn't correct !");
    }

    if (conditionLondon && conditionCanberra && conditionToronto) {
    window.location.href = "mypage.html";
    }
return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="return Distance();" method="POST">
      <p>
          <label for="dLondon">Distance from London</label>
          <input type="number" id="dLondon" name="dLondon" min="0" required>
          <label for="dLondon">miles</label>
      </p>
      <p>
          <label for="dCanberra">Distance from Canberra</label>
          <input type="number" id="dCanberra" name="dCanberra" min="0" required>
          <label for="dCanberra">miles</label>
      </p>        
      <p>
          <label for="dToronto">Distance from Toronto</label>
          <input type="number" id="dToronto" name="dToronto" min="0" required>
          <label for="dToronto">miles</label>
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "hijacking" the submit event for validating the form input, use the `invalid` event. You can use the attributes `min` and `max` (among others) to decide if the value is valid. The form will only submit if the form is valid, and you can use the standard `action` attribute on the form to specify the URL.

```js
document.forms.form.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(`${e.target.title} Distance isn't correct !`);
}, true);
```

```html
<form name="form" action="otherpage.html" method="POST">
  <p>
    <label for="dLondon">Distance from London</label>
    <input type="number" id="dLondon" name="dLondon"
      min="3900" max="5200" title="London" required>
    <label for="dLondon">miles</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="dCanberra">Distance from Canberra</label>
    <input type="number" id="dCanberra" name="dCanberra"
      min="5500" max="6700" title="Canberra" required>
    <label for="dCanberra">miles</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="dOttawa">Distance from Ottawa</label>
    <input type="number" id="dOttawa" name="dOttawa"
      min="6700" max="9300" title="Ottawa" required>
    <label for="dOttawa">miles</label>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't solve my problem. I want the user to be able to enter an incorrect value.